# Creating xml in c#

Tags: c#

Hi
I am creating an xml programatically.I am using namespace.In some places i dont need the namespace and so i am passing String.Empty.My element names contains colon ex gd:City.The problem is if i am passing null in the third parameter of createElement then in output i am getting City and not gd:city.How do i solve this problem.I need the o/p as gd:City at the same time i dont want to pass the namespace.

Regards
Sanchaita Chakraborty

Comment: If you prefix an element with `gd:` then you are using the `gd` namespace

Comment: So you want namespace but don't want to pass it yourself? How about a wrapper method that will add the namespace for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NameSpaceManager. Something like:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(myXmlDocument.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("gd", "http://mynamespacehere");
XmlNode nde = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("gd", "NewElement", "http://mynamespacehere");
```

Edit : As per the other poster's comments, you can't create an element name containing a colon (see the [W3Spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) and a tut on namespaces [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp)). If the element HAS a colon (:), it means that you are ALREADY using a namespace - look for a corresponding xmlns:gd="http://mynamespacehere" in a parent node of your City element (or City itself).

"gd" is just a placeholder (called a prefix) for the namespace. Your element is City, in a namespace - I don't have your complete XML message - for which the prefix "gd" was assigned.

Comment: In some cases i want to keep the namespace as null.But on doing this i am losing the prefix